# When is activityGroup onPause () method is called

Tags: android, android-intent, activitygroup

I am using ActivityGroup to handle the list of Activities,In the last Activity of the activityGroup,I am using Alert handler to show popup,and flow comes to first activity of Activity Group(On Resume of ActivityGroup is not called) where the code is there to launch the next Activity which is not part of same Activity Group,In case, where crashing is happening to me,On Pause of whole ActivityGroup is not getting called,But in some places where it works ,On Pause of whole ActivityGroup is getting called.

Anyone handled this weird scenario?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPause() - mainly: 
In situations where the system needs more memory it may kill paused processes to reclaim resources. Because of this, you should be sure that all of your state is saved by the time you return from this function. In general onSaveInstanceState(Bundle) is used to save per-instance state in the activity and this method is used to store global persistent data (in content providers, files, etc.)

Comment: One more thing,When i navigate to second activity in activityGroup and if i keep it idle for 5 sec -10 sec,It is not calling onPause of the Activity/Nor activity Group,It crashes in same way when i launch from the last activity in activity group to new activity.